# Multiple File from Same Form with Different Name Uploading

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am Trying to Upload two file with from Same form with Different File name.

The First File is always Uploading But the Other one never Uploading.

code for Model is:

```
 public function add_imgup()
  {      
        $this->uppdf();
        $this->upphoto();
  }
  public function upphoto()
  {

        $upload = array();
        $current_timestamp = time();
        $image_name = $current_timestamp.'_image';
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('file_upload_absolute_path')."pdf/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|PDF|DOC|doc|docx';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['file_name'] = $image_name;
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $file_image = $this->upload->do_upload('ccv');
        $image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
  }
  public function uppdf()
  {

        $upload = array();
        $current_timestamp = time();
        $image_name = $current_timestamp.'_image';
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('file_upload_absolute_path')."photo/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['file_name'] = $image_name;
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $file_image = $this->upload->do_upload('iimg');
        $image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
   }
```

Comment: what is the error you getting from upload library?

Comment: Are the names of both file input fields unique?

Comment: Yes The Names are unique

Comment: Any further info? like the HTML form? anything?

Comment: No.. Nothing like that.

Comment: @WebDevelopment What Hashem is asking for is the HTML for the form, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `print_r($_FILE)` after submitting the form to confirm the you submitted correct form, also check your form is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`